# Como evito que elementos se repitan dentro de un foreach c# ef-codefirst mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, foreach

```
public static List<string[]> GetIEWithSubSubClasificación(List<VoucherModel> lstVoucher, List<CuentaContableModel> lstCuentaContable ,List<string> listaSubSubClasificacion)
{
    List<string[]> ReturnValues = new List<string[]>();

    decimal TotalSumasResultadoPerdidas = 0;
    decimal TotalSumasResultadoGanancias = 0;
    int NumeroDeColumnas = 3;
    //List<CuentaContableModel> ListaCuentas = ObjCliente.CtaContable.ToList();
    //var lstSubSubCategorias = ListaCuentas.Where(x => x.SubSubClasificacion != null).Select(x => x.SubSubClasificacion).FirstOrDefault();
    int ContadorDeIteracion = 0;
    foreach (CuentaContableModel Cuenta in lstCuentaContable)
    {

        List<DetalleVoucherModel> lstDetalle = lstVoucher.SelectMany(x => x.ListaDetalleVoucher).Where(r => r.ObjCuentaContable.CuentaContableModelID == Cuenta.CuentaContableModelID).ToList();

        if (lstDetalle.Count == 0)
            continue;

        if (Cuenta.Clasificacion == ClasificacionCtaContable.RESULTADOGANANCIA)
        {
            decimal SumasDebitosEstaCuenta = 0;
            decimal SumasCreditosEstaCuenta = 0;

            SumasDebitosEstaCuenta = GetTotalDebe(lstDetalle);
            SumasCreditosEstaCuenta = GetTotalHaber(lstDetalle);

            decimal TotalSaldoEstaCuenta = SumasDebitosEstaCuenta - SumasCreditosEstaCuenta;
            //string Fecha = ParseExtensions.ToDD_MM_AAAA(lstDetalle.First().FechaDoc);
            var CodigoInterno = Cuenta.CodInterno;
            var CodigoInternoSubSub = Cuenta.SubSubClasificacion.CodigoInterno;
```

En esta parte meto la subsubclasificación la idea sería
que solo aparezca una sola vez la susubclasificación de una cuenta contable y luego se imprimieran las 
cuentas contables que pertenecen a esa subsubclasificación.
 Lo que pasa realmente es que por cada cuenta contable se imprime
 la subsubclasificación osea se repite si existen 
varias cuentas contables que pertenecen a una subsubclasificacion
¿Existe alguna manera de hacer que no se repitan? y queden como el ideal que dije?

```
                    string[] subsubrow = new string[NumeroDeColumnas];
                    subsubrow[0] = CodigoInternoSubSub + "   " + 
                     Cuenta.GetSubSubClasificacionName();
                    ReturnValues.Add(subsubrow);



                string[] IEstResultRow = new string[NumeroDeColumnas];
                    IEstResultRow[0] = Cuenta.CodInterno;
                    IEstResultRow[1] = Cuenta.nombre;
                    TotalSumasResultadoGanancias += Math.Abs(TotalSaldoEstaCuenta);
                    IEstResultRow[2] = ParseExtensions.NumberWithDots_para_BalanceGeneral(Math.Abs(TotalSaldoEstaCuenta));

                  ReturnValues.Add(IEstResultRow);



             //guardaremos el resultado del rellenado y orden de los  resultados en el array "ReturnValues" este contendrá lo necesario para enviarselo al controlador y este plasme el resultado en la vista.
        }

    }
```

Acá dejaré una foto para que vean como sale el resultado

[image]

Si se dan cuenta las que están marcadas con rojo son 3 osea que hay 3 cuentas contables que tienen la misma subsubclasificacion (lo que se está repitiendo) la idea seria que fuera solo 1  Agradecería una pequeña ayuda muchas gracias.

Comment: la verdad no entiendo el codigo, mezclas una parte de linq con otra que itera un foreach, defines listas con clases pero el resultado termina siendo `IEstResultRow` que es un array de string, todo eso porque? si conoces linq y sabes de clases y list aplica el codigo de forma consistente

Comment: porque haces un foreach de `lstCuentaContable` para despues validar si es igual a `ClasificacionCtaContable.RESULTADOGANANCIA` porque no directo un linq y en el where que retorne esa lista directamente

Comment: Llevo poco tiempo trabajando con linq y toda esta plataforma... toda la información que hay que llevar a la vista esta en 3 tablas y se me ocurria que llamarlas y combinarlas para retornar un array con todo lo que necesito de esas tablas era una de las maneras de llegar al resultado. Estoy abierto a cualquier critica constructiva gracias por tus comentarios los tomaré encuenta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De forma rapida si entender del todo el codigo el resultado final podrias aplicar un `group by` de `linq`

Pero para eso el resultado no puede ser un array de string, debes definir una clases como ser

```
public class EstResult
{
    public string CodInterno {get;set;}
    public string nombre {get;set;}
    public string TotalSaldoEstaCuenta {get;set;}
}
```

Para luego unir los datos que vas a retornar

```
TotalSumasResultadoGanancias += Math.Abs(TotalSaldoEstaCuenta);

EstResult item = new EstResult()
{
    CodInterno = Cuenta.CodInterno,
    nombre = Cuenta.nombre,
    TotalSaldoEstaCuenta = ParseExtensions.NumberWithDots_para_BalanceGeneral(Math.Abs(TotalSaldoEstaCuenta))
};

ReturnValues.Add(item);
```

Esa seia la parte final donde agregas el item, entonces podrias aplicar un agrupado

```
var result = from item in ReturnValues
              group item by item.nombre into g
              select new {
                 nombre = g.Key,
                 subitem = g.Select(x=> new {
                              CodInterno = x.CodInterno,
                              nombre = x.nombre,
                              TotalSaldoEstaCuenta = x.TotalSaldoEstaCuenta
                           })
              };
```

Lo que estoy intentando armar es una jerarquia, algo estilo un arbol donde tengas un padre y los subitems para que puedas usar en la generar de la tabla